# i want to get all the verified usernames from mysql table and send the data in res.json

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, json

i am new to nodejs developement and i made a simple app for registeration and login. I have a column (isVerified) and i marked it as 1 = verified and 0 = not verfied. My example table as below

| userid | username | password | isverfied |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 | ***** | 1 |
| 2 | user2 | ***** | 0 |
| 3 | user3 | ***** | 0 |
| 4 | user4 | ***** | 1 |
| 5 | user5 | ***** | 1 |

Now i want to get all the verified users from the above table and parse it to res.json.

When i am trying to get it done. I can able to get all the verified usernames from the table but i am not able to achieve to send it to the res.json.

my code

```
    var verified = 1;
    var userssqlquery = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE isVerified = ?';
    var insert = [verified];
    var sqlquery = mysql.format(userssqlquery, insert);
    var connection = mysql.createConnection(dbConfig.UserDB);
    connection.connect();
    connection.query(sqlquery, function(error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
          res.status(500).json({
            status: false,
            statusCode: 500,
            error,
            message: 'there are some error with query'
          });
          console.log('Step: 14');
        }else{
            var resultLength = results.length;
            var usernme = results.userName;

            for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var userNames = results[i].userName;
            console.log(userNames)
            }

            res.status(200).json({
                status: true,
                statusCode: 200,
                verifieduser: resultLength,
                results
            });
        }
    });
```

and json result is as below

```
{
    "status": true,
    "statusCode": 200,
    "verifieduser": 3,
    "results": [
        {
            "userName": "user1",
            "userId": "098cfe05-6f61-4171-b8fc-d71d530c9846",
            "password": "*******",,
            "isVerified": 1,
        },
        {
            "userName": "user4",
            "userId": "10c9f199-ae29-47de-9217-bd15c67f53bd",
            "password": "*******",
            "isVerified": 1
        },
        {
            "userName": "user5",
            "userId": "392898d6-2885-4184-9abe-0bebf480984b",
            "password": "*******",
            "isVerified": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

and my console log for the below blockcode is

```
for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var userNames = results[i].userName;
            console.log(userNames)
            }
```

console log is

```
user1
user4
user5
```

now what i want is to show the username inside the json response as below

```
{
    "status": true,
    "statusCode": 200,
    "verifieduser": 3,
    "results": [
        {
            "user1"
        },
        {
            "user4"
        },
        {
            "user5",
        }
    ]
}

or like this 

{
    "status": true,
    "statusCode": 200,
    "verifieduser": 3,
    "results": [
        {
            "user1","user4","user5"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map over the `results` array and return the usernames.

```
const usernames = results.map(result => result.userName)

res.status(200).json({
  // ...
  results: usernames,
})
```

Comment: Thank you very for your quick response and it works like a charm........